# Notification + Subscription: Can this combination recipe be used to create notification system similar to Facebook's?

Tags: 7, social-network, notifications

I understand that this combination of Notification + Subscription modules can accomplish a lot of different notification setups. However, I am only looking to emulate the notification system similar to Facebook, as in this example:

[image]

Can anyone provide any tip or guidance as to how this combination may be configured to achieve this goal?

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1):

you can use my module for this [Total Subscription](https://drupal.org/project/total_subscription).

> Total Subscription provides functionality which would allow the user to subscribe to node pages, taxonomy terms, etc. The main feature which distinguishes it from other subscription modules is that it allows subscription for Anonymous along with Authenticated users.

Comment: Thanks for disclosing that this is your module.  Instead of just copying the same answer for a few questions, could you tailor the answers a little to explain how your module could apply to the particular situation?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Menu Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_badges) module can be used to add such notifications to any **menu item** and/or **menu tab** of your choice. Here are some details about it (from its project page):

> Provides a method for adding iOS-style badges to menu items. (see screenshot)
>
> [image]
>
> #### Adding Badges to Menus
>
> Once enabled, go to `Administration > Structure > Menus`, and click "list links" next to the menu containing the target item. Click "edit" next to the item and select the badge to display with the Display Menu Badge select box.
>
> #### Adding Badges to Tabs
>
> For adding badges to menu tabs, there is a tab under `Administration > Structure > Menus` called "Tab Menu Badges". Search for the menu router path of the tab you want to alter, then select a badge from the corresponding select box.
>
> #### Badge Types
>
> The module includes five example badges, and new badges can be created easily with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). Modules can also supply their own badges with a hook implementation. See the [README.txt](http://drupalcode.org/project/menu_badges.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt) file for details.

Because of how it integrates with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, you basically reduce the solution for any type of notification to something like this:

- **Step 1**: Just create an appropriate view of it, create a menu item or menu tab for that view.
- **Step 2**: Do a 15 seconds [Menu Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_badges) configuration to tell it which menu item/tab you used for it in your view.

#### Video tutorials:

- [Defining Menu Badges with Views in Drupal](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AoZQNg5QOI) (from the module maintainer).
- [Drupal 7 Menu Badges Module](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iz25ED1ECv8).