# How to create notifications like Facebook about pending workflow approvals?

Tags: 8, notifications, workbench

Is it possible in Drupal 8 to setup notification bar as in Facebook?

**Update**:

I have different roles and I am using workbench for applying workflow. I have three transition attached with role like draft, approved, published. When user like reporter who have only draft transition going to save content at that time a user like editor who have right for transition like approve will get notify on screen when login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at one of the answers to "[Notification + Subscription: Can this combination recipe be used to create notification system similar to Facebook's?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/31113/39516)", which explains how the [Menu Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_badges) module can be used for this. The result of using it looks as in this example:

[image]

The current status of this module for D8 is like so:

> The 8.x-1.x-dev release includes all the functionality of the Drupal 7 version. However, it is not yet completely working with the new caching that Drupal 8 does. Badges are getting cached and don't change when they should. Once that is fixed, a stable release will be created.

To implement it for supporting what you decribed in your *update*, you only have to create an appropriate view (using views) with as results the updated content that the editor should be notified about.

Comment: Actually I have  different roles and I am using workbench for applying workflow.  

I have three transition attached with role like draft, approved, published.

When user like reporter who have only draft transition going to save content at that time a user like editor who have right for transition like approve will get notify on screen when login.

Thanks & regards